# how to write double superscript over \xrightarrow

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, arrows

Instead of one line above the arrow I want to be able to write two lines over it. How can I achieve this?
With this code I can only achieve one line:

```
\xrightarrow[]{something}
```

Comment: One line above the arrow is not really clear to me. Please explain your question more, and don't forget adding a code.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve. That is how us what you have so far (the code + a picture of the compiled result) and then maybe grab paint and try to illustrate the wanted behaviour with that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Abusing a little bit the `\substack` macro from `amsmath` (whose original purpose is for multiline sub/superscripts in operators):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
A \xrightarrow[\substack{def \\ \text{below}}]{\substack{abc \\ \text{above}}} B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: What about two lines under the arrow?

Comment: Same thing, with the optional argument. See edit.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

you mean something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
    \usepackage{stackengine}
    \newcommand\stackrightarrow[3]{%
        \mathrel{{{\stackon[4pt]{$\xrightarrow[#3]{#1}$}{$\scriptscriptstyle#2$}}}}}
    \begin{document}
        $   a \stackrightarrow{x}{y}{z} b$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, welcome to TeX.SE, from next time, please add a MWE to show what you have tried so-far.

Comment: Thank you. This also worked for me.